# Obtener hora y minuto actual mysql

Tags: mysql

Quisiera saber como obtener únicamente la *hora* y *minuto* actual en *Mysql* ya que he intentado varias opciones

La primera me muestra hora, minuto y segundo, las otras no me dan resultado.

```
select time (NOW()) as hora

select DATE_FORMAT time ((now),'%H:%i')

SELECT  DATE_FORMAT(time NOW(), '%H:%i);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No entendí bien pero creo que buscas esta linea

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW( ), "%H:%i:%S" )
```

saludos!

Comment: `%I` obtendrías la hora nuevamente , los minutos se obtienen con `%i` **minúscula**

Comment: Tienes razon, si dejo la I en mayuscula me marca una hora diferente, si dejo la i minuscula me manda la hora actual, thanks.

Comment: @AlbertoArenas así es , es por eso que le indiqué a Oscar para que haga  la modificación.

Comment: ya modifique gracias !

Answer (score 1):

Horas  [HOUR](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_hour)

```
SELECT HOUR(NOW());
```

Minutos  [MINUTE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_minute)

```
select MINUTE(now());
```

Segundos  [SECOND](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_second)

```
select SECOND(now())
```

O directamente con [DATE_FORMAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW( ), "%H:%i:%S" )
```

> Para más información revisar [Funciones de Hora y Fecha](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html)